# Using Django Admin panel object creation functionality with Multiple-to-Multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to use django admin board functionality to be able to insert data within admin panel into tables with one-to-multiple and multiple-to-multiple relations. I used `__str__` functionality (Python 3.6) in order to create understandable strings in admin panel instead of `"Testcase object(1)"` like description to be able to select proper testcase id and testrun id for executedtests model. But it looks like admin panel during executedtest object creation instead of testcase id value and testrun id value tries to set foreign int keys to a corresponding text value.
I miserably fail with error:

```
tc = Testcases.objects.get(pk=self.testcase_id)
...
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Testcases'
```

Models:

```
class Testcases(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Testcase: {self.name}"


class Testruns(models.Model):
    starttime = models.TimeField()
    endtime = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Testrun: {self.starttime} - {self.endtime}"


class Executedtests(models.Model):
    testcase_id = models.ForeignKey("testcases", models.CASCADE)
    testrun_id = models.ForeignKey("testruns", models.CASCADE)
    teststart = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    testend = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    def __str__(self):
        tc = Testcases.objects.get(pk=self.testcase_id)
        tr = Testruns.objects.get(pk=self.testrun_id)
        return f"{tc}(tr), Start: {self.teststart}, End: {self.testend}"
```

Inside app `admin.py` I just register all those models.

The select tag of the admin form looks ok though:

```
<select id="id_testcase_id" name="testcase_id">
    <option value="1">Testcase: Test1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: You defined a foreign key as `testcase_id` (and others with `_id`), but the `_id` is automatically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a `fieldname` that is a `ForeignKey`, Django automatically adds an extra field `fieldname_id` that contains the primary key of that object. So here Django has constructed a `testcase_id_id`, which contains the primary key of the `Testcases` instance it refers to, but this makes it semantically rather "*ugly*".

It is therefore more consistent to name the relation after the item it refers to, and let Django generate the `fieldname_id`, such that you can still extract (and query with) that value.

A minimal fix is thus:

```
class Executedtests(models.Model):
    # rename the relations (drop the _id suffix)
    testcase = models.ForeignKey("testcases", models.CASCADE)
    testrun = models.ForeignKey("testruns", models.CASCADE)
    teststart = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    testend = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    def __str__(self):
        tc = Testcases.objects.get(pk=self.testcase_id)
        tr = Testruns.objects.get(pk=self.testrun_id)
        return f"{tc}(tr), Start: {self.teststart}, End: {self.testend}"
```

Your view will then work, since `testcase_id` will contain no longer a `Testcases` instance (the foreign key takes the type of the model you refer to), but the primary key.

By calling `someexecutedtests.testcase` you thus do *not* obtain the primary key of that `testcase`, but the `Testcases` instance itself (in case it was not fetched yet, Django will usually perform another query).

Comment: Very much appreciated for an instant solution! I will accept answer within 7 minutes when stackexchange allows me to